# syntax error in while and end while in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an error in `while` and `end while` in my code ... 
here is my code:

```
SET i = 0;
WHILE i<n DO
INSERT INTO bo_search_engine_scenario (version, mcs, name, factor, tracking_code) 
          SELECT version, mcs, name, factor, tracking_code FROM  bo_search_engine_scenario_temp LIMIT i,1;
END WHILE
```

Why does it give me `while is not valid at this position`?

Comment: is this inside a Stored procedure  ?

Comment: nop it is not  inside procedure

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2039f/1) using `WHILE`.

Comment: You can't just type any old command anywhere and expect it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a while loop outside of a stored procedure.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html

There is an example on the documentation. A quick Google search will also give you plenty of information on stored procedures.

Comment: also i tried now using procedure and the same errors appear

Comment: Can you please post the procedure you attempted

Comment: That is a stupid restriction! I was trying to test something in a regular query window; I should not have to create a dummy proc first to testing something.